# Swipe detection down'n work always

Tags: jquery, mobile, swipe

I work on phonegap app and I have a problem with the swipe event.The swipe(left or right) doesn't work always .
THe structure

```
$(document).on('swiperight',function(event,data){
        event.stopImmediatePropagation(); 

            alert('left');
        });

    $(document).on('swipeleft',function(event,data){
            event.stopImmediatePropagation(); 

            alert('right');
        });
```

Sometimes I need to make 3-4 swipes to appear the alert.
Can I reduce the horizontal distance that define a swipe or what can I do to works anytime?

Comment: is your device ready? onDeviceReady event? this is a must I think. Also check to use proper query

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this,all you need to do is call the two functions under

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  SwipeRight();
  SwipeLeft();
    };

function SwipeRight() {
$(document).on('swiperight',function(event,data){
event.stopImmediatePropagation(); 

            alert('left');
        });
}
function SwipeLeft() {
    $(document).on('swipeleft',function(event,data){
         event.stopImmediatePropagation(); 

            alert('right');
        });
}
```